# Split a (Kibana) histogram bar into multiple sections (see image)

Tags: elasticsearch, data-visualization, kibana

**The Problem:**

I've been struggeling with Kibana (v7.5.1) Visualization for some time to create (what I thought would be a) simple histogram, from ElasticSearch data.

I'll simplify my problem to make it more general: Let's say I have shop, selling three different items labeled **X**, **Y** and **Z**. I also have known, regular customers, denoted as customer **A**, **B** and **C**.

Now, every time a purchase is made, a `json` file is successfully indexed by *ElasticSearch*, and it looks something like the following

```
{
  "PurchaseOrder": {
    "Customer": "A",
    "item_id": 2,
    ...
  }
}
```

Note that *ElasticSearch* indexes the customer as a text string, and the item's ID as a number (`long`). Then, I want to create a histogram showing what each customer bought over some arbitrary time period. Specifically, I want a graph as shown at the bottom of this post (drawn in MS Paint). From the graph, I'll be able to tell the total number of items a customer bought (e.g. customer **A** bought a total number of 6 items), but also how many of a specific item (out of the six items customer **A** bought, one was item **X**).

**I've tried:**

I plotted `counts` on the y-axis and and `terms`->`Customer` on the x-axis, which essentially gave me a histogram showing the total number of (all) items a customer has bought. I then thought it might be possible to split the *Metrics* y-axis into multiple axes, each individually filtered by field `item_id`, but apparently, `filter` is not an option for *Metrics* of type `count`..

[image: Simple example drawing made in MS Paint]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of googling, trying and failing I eventually found a working solution. Under **Buckets**, I clicked **Add**, **Split series**, chose Sub aggregation **Filters**. I then added five filters, and set one for each sales item: `PurchaseOrder.item_id : 1` with label `item V`. It's a little inconveinient to have an individual filter for every item, but at least it works.

I'll gladly accept another answer if someone's able to provide a simpler solution..

I apologize for the "wierd" fonts in the image below: I had to edit it in MS Paint in order to have the labels match those of the original post/question.

[image: Resultinggraph]